# English term for a White-Teeth-Fetish

Tags: word-choice

What is the English term for being sexually attracted to people with white teeth?

Comment: *Odontophilia* doesn't quite work. Much broader that a fetish for white teeth.

Comment: How about lefkodontophilia?